# Something wrong with my SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

It tells me I have an error somewhere here:

```
if not exists (select * from ARCUS where CUSTOMER_NO = a) 
begin 
    insert into ARCUS (CUSTOMER_NO) values (a)
end
```

Comment: You can only use `IF` and `BEGIN` statements inside a stored procedure, not in queries.

Comment: CUSTOMER_NO = a - might need quotes.

Answer (score 2):

@Barmar has the good solution but i can't +1 the answer...

**Just add a unique key on "CUSTOMER_NO"**

You should also write your field and tbl name in lowercase for more readability when you use mysql.

```
ALTER TABLE `arcus` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_customer_no` (`customer_no`);
```

And then do :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `arcus` SET `customer_no` = 'a';
```

Comment: Juste add a unique key  - if only it was that simple to get it past change control..

Comment: It seems likely that this would be the primary key of the table.

Comment: Which change? in the exemple he try to insert if not exist ....
That will ignore the insert row if the unique key value allready exist.
A primary is unique you just need to add do an INSERT IGNORE

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is inside a stored procedure, you're missing the semicolon after the `INSERT` query.

```
if not exists (select * from ARCUS where CUSTOMER_NO = a) 
begin 
    insert into ARCUS (CUSTOMER_NO) values (a);
end
```

But if `CUSTOMER_NO` is a unique key in the table, you can do it with a single query:

```
insert ignore into ARCUS (CUSTOMER_NO) values (a);
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't have to be in a procedure.

Comment: I have updated it to say "insert ignore into ARCUS (COMPANY_CD, CUSTOMER_NO) values ('CU', 'a');" now it doesn't give an error but it also doesn't do anything.

Comment: What is the datatype of `customer_no`? If it's `INT`, `'a'` is not a valid value for it.

Comment: This is why database questions are often far easier to answer if you take the time to post a representative schema. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` helps generate one of those for an existing table and can be edited to trim out irrelevant columns. If this column must be unique, a `UNIQUE` constraint is the way to do it, not test-on-insert.

Comment: I forgot there needs to be a key, but now I'm getting another error. insert ignore into ARCUS (COMPANY_CD, CUSTOMER_NO, RECORD_KEY.COMPANY_CD.CUSTOMER_NO.OPTIONAL_SHIPTO) values ('CU', 'A', 'CUA    ');

Comment: It should just be `(COMPANY_CD, CUSTOMER_NO, RECORD_KEY)`, get rid of the extra `.COMPANY_CD.CUSTOMER_NO.OPTIONAL_SHIPTO` after that.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as variant, you can something like:

```
insert into ARCUS (CUSTOMER_NO) 
select 'a' 
where not exists (select 1 from ARCUS where CUSTOMER_NO = 'a');
```

Comment: I suspect `a` is a parameter to the procedure, not a literal, so it shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: actually a was a literal, I was just testing with short strings.

Comment: @skirsch00 - If so, then you need quotes as Barmar noticed.